# Is it possible to draw a diagonal line using CSS3?

Tags: css

I know that is possible to [create a circle using CSS3](http://www.cardeo.ca/2010/how-to-create-circles-with-css3-and-no-images)

Is it possible to draw a diagonal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

yes it is, there is more then one possibility:

You could use a `hr` element or a other element and rotate it. Here is a demo:

And yes it works in IE to :)

http://jsfiddle.net/LqFAX/

```
   -moz-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  
     -o-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  
-webkit-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  
    -ms-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  
        transform: rotate(7.5deg);  
           filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand',  
                  M11=0.9914448613738104, M12=-0.13052619222005157,M21=0.13052619222005157, M22=0.9914448613738104);
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.9914448613738104, M12=-0.13052619222005157, M21=0.13052619222005157, M22=0.9914448613738104,sizingMethod='auto expand')";

             zoom: 1;
```

Comment: A forked version of that same fiddle that puts a diagonal line through a DIV to make it look like a marked off calendar day. http://jsfiddle.net/LqFAX/2396/

Answer (score 6):

Here is a complete example, you just need to play with an angle and translation base on your dimensions.

```
<div style="background-color: #BCBCBC; width: 100px; height: 50px; padding: 0; margin: 0">
    <div style="width: 112px; height: 47px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; -webkit-transform:   translateY(-20px) translateX(5px) rotate(27deg); "></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "play with an angel" <3

Answer (score 2):

You can:

1. create html element (div)
2. set background color to transparent
3. set color to one border
4. rotate

Comment: @arjan do you mean the webkit rotate CSS selector?

Comment: rotate from CSS 2D transforms (transform: rotate(45deg);)

Comment: @janoChen yes, -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);

Comment: @arjan Firefox and chrome are OK but I think it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: css 2d transforms support will be available in ie9

Comment: @arjan I'm afraid that IE9 will be widely used around 2016