# draw diagonal lines in div background with CSS

Tags: css, background, line, css-shapes, diagonal

I have a div for a preview box:

```css
.preview-content {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAGklEQVQIW2NkYGD4D8SMQAwGcAY2AbBKDBUAVuYCBQPd34sAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview-content">PREVIEW</div>
```

### Question: how to add diagonal lines to div background like in the picture?

*note: with CSS only if possible*

[image: preview]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you just want to add two lines?

Comment: yes, only 2 like in picture

Comment: if you need to design Box model Inputs for Margin or Padding inputs as like Browser Margin-padding box model https://jsfiddle.net/bx2paunL/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do it something like this:

```css
.background {
  background-color: #BCBCBC;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.line1 {
  width: 112px;
  height: 47px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px) translateX(5px) rotate(27deg);
  position: absolute;
  /* top: -20px; */
}

.line2 {
  width: 112px;
  height: 47px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(20px) translateX(5px) rotate(-26deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -33px;
  left: -13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/giodamelio/htg0Lqd2/1/).

Improved version of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17854173/2194052) for your purpose.

Comment: With `-webkit-transform` will work only on WebKit based browsers. I suggest to specify the standard W3C `transform` rule as first step, then specify other browser-specific rule, such `-webkit-transform`, `-moz-transform`, `-ms-transform`, `-o-transform`.

Answer (score 209):

Solution that automatically scales to dimensions of an element would be usage of CSS3 linear-gradient connected with calc() as shown below. (There were some issues with Chrome in times of v30+ versions that this answer originally described but looks like they got resolved in the meantime and in v90+ it works as expected).

```css
.crossed {
     background: 
         linear-gradient(to top left,
             rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
             rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% - 0.8px),
             rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,
             rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% + 0.8px),
             rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),
         linear-gradient(to top right,
             rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
             rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% - 0.8px),
             rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,
             rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% + 0.8px),
             rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<textarea class="crossed"></textarea>
```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle in case you want to play with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/zaxy6pmn/

Comment: Looks mostly OK in Chrome 39, but the lower-right "arm" has an extra pixel. Depending on what's around it this may not be noticeable except at very small sizes, e.g. 5x5 pixels.

Comment: Nice solution. Updated it to background repeat: http://jsfiddle.net/6q4m4ww8/ 

My issue now is how to add a distance between x-es

Comment: You mean something like [http://jsfiddle.net/8f5rgn8t/](http://jsfiddle.net/8f5rgn8t/)? ;) (though probably need a little bit more of tweaking for thicker lines, as each line has one end clipped to vertical side of bounding box and second one to horizontal)

Comment: What if I wanted to change the background color to grey instead of white?

Comment: @Bargain23 Change the rgba values to be grey values.

Comment: Best :) As for me

Comment: Perfect reusable solution

Comment: When my containing `div` is just 2px tall (i.e. the line is nearly horizontal), both Firefox and Chrome seem to fade out the beginning and end of the lines.  I'm guessing this is antialiasing?  Any way to turn it off?

Comment: Excellent solution.  Works in Firefox version 109.0.1.

Comment: Unfortunately not supported by WeasyPrint PDF printer (as of v61.1), below .diag class from @intrepidis worked very well.

Answer (score 40):

You can use SVG to draw the lines.

```css
.diag {
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><path d='M1 0 L0 1 L99 100 L100 99' fill='black' /><path d='M0 99 L99 0 L100 1 L1 100' fill='black' /></svg>");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="diag" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

Have a play here: http://jsfiddle.net/tyw7vkvm

Comment: Nice! Was looking for a solution to emulate a "crossed out" price and this worked great with a few minor alterations http://jsfiddle.net/tyw7vkvm/636/ 

Comment: @intrepidis How to increase the thickness of the lines?

Comment: @TonyMathew here is 4 pixel thick: `<path d='M 4 0 L 4 0 L 0 0 L 0 4 L 96 100 L 100 100 L 100 96' fill='black' /><path d='M 96 0 L 96 0 L 100 0 L 100 4 L 4 100 L 0 100 L 0 96' fill='black' />` just change the 4's and 96's to whatever thickness you need. (e.g. 2 and 98, 5 and 95)

Answer (score 20):

All other answers to this 3-year old question require CSS3 (or SVG). However, it can also be done with nothing but lame old CSS2:

```css
.crossed {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.crossed:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 1px;
    bottom: 1px;
    border-width: 149px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black white;
}

.crossed:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-width: 149px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class='crossed'></div>
```

### Explanation, as requested:

Rather than actually drawing diagonal lines, it occurred to me we can instead color the so-called *negative space* triangles adjacent to where we want to see these lines. The trick I came up with to accomplish this exploits the fact that multi-colored CSS borders are bevelled diagonally:

```css
.borders {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    border-width: 40px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red blue green yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='borders'></div>
```

To make things fit the way we want, we choose an inner rectangle with dimensions 0 and LINE_THICKNESS pixels, and another one with those dimensions reversed:

```css
.r1 { width: 10px;
      height: 0;
      border-width: 40px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: red blue;
      margin-bottom: 10px; }
.r2 { width: 0;
      height: 10px;
      border-width: 40px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: blue transparent; }
```

```html
<div class='r1'></div><div class='r2'></div>
```

Finally, use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-selectors and position relative/absolute as a neat way to insert the borders of both of the above rectangles on top of each other into your HTML element of choice, to produce a diagonal cross. Note that results probably look best with a thin LINE_THICKNESS value, such as 1px.

Comment: Yeah, nice trick, but ignores one assumption of original question: `width: 100%` of `div` to be crossed ;) Though, to be fair, guessing from accepted answer, looks like it wasn't hard requirement.

Answer (score 16):

[intrepidis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28974253/6270906) on this page using a background SVG in CSS has the advantage of scaling nicely to any size or aspect ratio, though the SVG uses `<path>`s with a fill that doesn't scale so well.

I've just updated the SVG code to use `<line>` instead of `<path>` and added `non-scaling-stroke` [vector-effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10357359/6270906) to prevent the strokes scaling with the container:

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
  <line x1='0' y1='0' x2='100' y2='100' stroke='black' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'/>
  <line x1='0' y1='100' x2='100' y2='0' stroke='black' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'/>
</svg>
```

Here's that dropped into the CSS from the original answer (with HTML made resizable):

```css
.diag {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><line x1='0' y1='0' x2='100' y2='100' stroke='black' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'/><line x1='0' y1='100' x2='100' y2='0' stroke='black' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="diag" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid; resize: both; overflow: auto"></div>
```

Comment: This is great for drawing lines, in contrast to other shapes/structures. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Please check the following.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
ctx.moveTo(0,100);
ctx.lineTo(200,0);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

CSS:

```
html, body { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#myCanvas {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  height: 102px;
  width: 202px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmqJf/4/)

Comment: notice that width is 100%, `width: 100%;` so box will be floating, so I can't write coordinates permanent into js

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```css
.crossed {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border:solid 1px;
    background-color: rgb(210, 137, 226);
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 15px,
      #ccc 10px,
      #ccc 20px
        ),
      repeating-linear-gradient(
        135deg,
        transparent,
        transparent 15px,
        #ccc 10px,
        #ccc 20px
      );
}
```

```html
<div class='crossed'>Hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

An svg dynamic solution for any screen is the following:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%"/>
  <line x1="100%" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%"/>
</svg>
```

And if you want to keep it in background use the `position: absolute` with top and left 0.

Answer (score 3):

you can use a CSS3 transform Property:

```
div
{
transform:rotate(Xdeg);
-ms-transform:rotate(Xdeg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(Xdeg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Xdeg = your value

For example...

You can make more div and use a z-index property.
So,make a div with line, and rotate it.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like the cross to be partially transparent, the naive approach would be to make `linear-gradient` colors semi-transparent. But that doesn't work out good due to the alpha blending at the intersection, producing a differently colored diamond. The solution to this is to leave the colors solid but add transparency to the gradient container instead:

```css
.cross {
  position: relative;
}
.cross::after {
  pointer-events: none;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}

.cross1::after {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 45%, rgba(255,0,0,0.35) 46%, rgba(255,0,0,0.35) 54%, transparent 55%),
    linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 45%, rgba(255,0,0,0.35) 46%, rgba(255,0,0,0.35) 54%, transparent 55%);
}

.cross2::after {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 45%, rgb(255,0,0) 46%, rgb(255,0,0) 54%, transparent 55%),
    linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 45%, rgb(255,0,0) 46%, rgb(255,0,0) 54%, transparent 55%);
  opacity: 0.35;
}

div { width: 180px; text-align: justify; display: inline-block; margin: 20px; }
```

```html
<div class="cross cross1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et dui imperdiet, dapibus augue quis, molestie libero. Cras nisi leo, sollicitudin nec eros vel, finibus laoreet nulla. Ut sit amet leo dui. Praesent rutrum rhoncus mauris ac ornare. Donec in accumsan turpis, pharetra eleifend lorem. Ut vitae aliquet mi, id cursus purus.</div>

<div class="cross cross2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et dui imperdiet, dapibus augue quis, molestie libero. Cras nisi leo, sollicitudin nec eros vel, finibus laoreet nulla. Ut sit amet leo dui. Praesent rutrum rhoncus mauris ac ornare. Donec in accumsan turpis, pharetra eleifend lorem. Ut vitae aliquet mi, id cursus purus.</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did this using the css `clip-path` property alongside *relative* and *absolute* positioning to create a more fancy cross.

```css
.cross {
  width:150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #555;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #efefef;
}

.cross .diag1{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  clip-path: polygon(90% 0, 100% 0%, 10% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background: #311B92;
}

.cross .diag2{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 10% 0, 100% 100%, 90% 100%);
  background: #1B5E20;
}
```

```html
<div class="cross">
  <div class="diag1"></div>
  <div class="diag2"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a [link to the code on codepen](https://codepen.io/nkemcels/pen/XWbgaXB) if you'd like to tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to draw arbitrary diagonal lines inside any div. My issue with the other answers posted is that none of them allowed to draw an arbitrary line from point A to point B without doing the trigonometry yourself for the angles. With javascript & CSS you can do this. Hope it's helpful, just specify a pair of points and you're golden.

```js
const objToStyleString = (obj) => {
  const reducer = (acc, curr) => acc += curr + ": " + obj[curr] + ";"; 
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(reducer, "")
};

const lineStyle = (xy1, xy2, borderStyle) => {
  const p1 = {x: xy1[0], y: xy1[1]};
  const p2 = {x: xy2[0], y: xy2[1]};
  
  const a = p2.x - p1.x;
  const xOffset = p1.x;
  const b = p2.y - p1.y;
  const yOffset = p1.y;
  
  const c = Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);
  
  const ang = Math.acos(a/c);
  
  const tX1 = `translateX(${-c/2 + xOffset}px) `;
  const tY1 = `translateY(${yOffset}px) `;
  const rot = `rotate(${ang}rad) `;
  const tX2 = `translateX(${c/2}px) `;
  const tY2 = `translateY(${0}px) `;
  
  return {
    "width": Math.floor(c) + "px",
    "height": "0px",
    "border-top": borderStyle,
    "-webkit-transform": tX1+tY1+rot+tX2+tY2,
    "position": "relative",
    "top": "0px",
    "left": "0px",
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
  };
};

function drawLine(parent, p1, p2, borderStyle) {
  const style = lineStyle(p1, p2, borderStyle);
  const line = document.createElement("div");
  line.style = objToStyleString(style);
  parent.appendChild(line);
}

drawLine(container, [100,5], [25,195], "1px dashed purple");
drawLine(container, [100,100], [190,190], "1px solid blue");
drawLine(container, [25,150], [175,150], "2px solid red");
drawLine(container, [25,10], [175,20], "5px dotted green");
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: #BCBCBC;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice proposal for more advance needs. why do you translate the div before and after the rotate ? It seems to work fine with a single translate by offset values with "transform-origin: top left;".

Answer (score -5):

```css
.borders {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    border-width: 40px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red blue green yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='borders'></div>
```