# CSS - If I make two diagonal lines to form an x Is there a way to place text at intersection?

Tags: css

I have the diagonal lines working as per [draw diagonal lines in div background with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012420/draw-diagonal-lines-in-div-background-with-css/30065150#30065150/%22draw%20diagonal%20lines%20in%20div%20background%20with%20CSS%22) and set as % to be responsive.

Trying to place letter's on the white spaces on each side of intersection of lines. i.e

above, below, left, right of intersection / centre

I can't get it to work.

I then want to set a full page image background slider with text overlay.

Comment: use divs and position them where you like

Comment: could you explain your requirement in detail.

Answer (score 2):

I figured a solution according to your requirement.

HTML:

```
<div class="crossed">
    <div style="text-align:center;">A</div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-top:1em;">B</div>
    <div style="float:right;margin-top:1em;">C</div>
    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:4em;">D</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.crossed 
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:linear-gradient(to top left,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% - 0.8px),
           rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% + 0.8px),
           rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),
       linear-gradient(to top right,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% - 0.8px),
           rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,
           rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% + 0.8px),
           rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
```

Demo is here : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uoc4g63p/)

Comment: Trying to understand how this works. When I change the margins to change position on the letters the whole area moves not just the letter. Is there a way to change the position of the letter in relation to the intersection e.g closer to intersection ?

Comment: Anyone got any ideas ?

Comment: I could really use a hand.