# create a dashed diagonal line with css linear-gradient

Tags: html, css

I need a dashed diagonal line inside a div.

in this tread [draw diagonal lines in div background with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012420/draw-diagonal-lines-in-div-background-with-css)

i found how to make a cross with this code

```
.crossed {

background: 
   linear-gradient(to top left,
       rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
       rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% - 0.8px),
       /*rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,*/
       rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% + 0.8px),
       rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),
   linear-gradient(to top right,
       rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
       rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% - 0.8px),
       rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,
       rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% + 0.8px),
       rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
```

by commenting out the line as shown above it removes 1 of the lines out of the x and leaves me with the diagonal line as needed.

but how can i make the line dashed?

the fiddle is here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuxcbqqq/1/)

thanks!

edit:
sorry, saw the 100px width in example code, the div is changing width and hight done by js. this changes the diagonal degrees, so  transform: rotate(-45deg); wont work

Comment: maybe try something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/bnxohckf/

Comment: that wont work because the div is changing width and height. so the diagonal is not always 45 deg

Comment: If an opaque background is ok to you, here is an awful hack http://jsfiddle.net/nuxcbqqq/9/

Comment: you just need to set a static width, I updated the fidde from @RaresHideg http://jsfiddle.net/bnxohckf/2/

Comment: the awful hack is showing nothing in the fiddle.

Comment: the static width wont work either because when the div is 100*150 then the diagonal is not 45 degrees anymore

Comment: You need `-webkit-`prefix for chrome : http://jsfiddle.net/nuxcbqqq/10/

Comment: I think your best bet for dynamic width is something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/u25q9uq4/1/ (updated)

Answer (score 3):

A simple option would be for you to use a svg for the dashed background

```
<div class='box'>
  <svg style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'>
      <line stroke-dasharray="5, 5"  x1="0" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
  </svg>
  <div>
  your content here over the svg
  </div>
</div>
```

demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/u25q9uq4/1/

if you don't want to you svg in code, you can still use it as a css background with base64,

```
div.box{
  position: relative;
  width: 211px; 
  height: 55px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiPjxsaW5lIHN0cm9rZS1kYXNoYXJyYXk9IjUsIDUiICB4MT0iMCIgeTE9IjEwMCUiIHgyPSIxMDAlIiB5Mj0iMCIgc3R5bGU9InN0cm9rZTpyZ2IoMjU1LDAsMCk7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjIiLz48L3N2Zz4=") no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/u25q9uq4/2/

I used [this tool](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/base64/base64.php) to convert the svg to base64

This is the final form of the svg converted

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%"><line stroke-dasharray="5, 5"  x1="0" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/></svg>
```

You can change the color and stroke of the dashed link in this example, convert it, and insert it into your css.

Best of luck.

EDIT: [Examples of svg dashed lines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray)

Comment: glad I could help.