# Roadmap Timeline ReactJS Design

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

so I have this design I want to make. Basically it is a timeline that goes from the lower-left to the upper-right part of the page. Additionally, I need to place some div elements between the lines.

I also would want to to be responsive, specifically, its length will decrease but I still want the lines going up to be prominent.

Are there any suggestions as to how I can make this with ReactJS and TailwindCSS?

[image: Mockup of the roadmap-timeline design]

The examples I found on the internet are online horizontal and vertical timeline-styles. There are no examples about curved timelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a timeline similar to the images you provided using mostly `grid`.

In the example I created, there are 3 [custom utilities](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-custom-utilities):

##### main.css:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .borderGray {
    @apply border-y-[1px] border-[lightgray] text-center;
  }

  .textClass {
    @apply m-2 break-words border-2 border-black text-[0.8rem] sm:text-sm md:text-base;
  }

  .slantedLine {
    background: linear-gradient(
      to top left,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) calc(50% - 1px),
      lightgray 50%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) calc(50% + 1px),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
    );
  }
}
```

1. The `borderGray` class creates a gray border on the top and bottom of an element and centers the text to the middle.
2. The `textClass` takes care of the `font-size` responsiveness. This class can be changed entirely. It just looked convenient here.
3. The `slantedLine` class creates a diagonal line crossing the element from the bottom-left corner to the upper-right corner. Here's the answer I used to get it: [draw diagonal lines in div background with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012420/draw-diagonal-lines-in-div-background-with-css)

---

Now, to the `HTML`.

I created three different variations that can be changed from one to the other depending on the screen size, in case you would like to use more than one variation in your responsive design.
This is what those variations look like:
[image: timeline]

This is what it looks like under the hood:
[image: under the hood]

##### HTML:

```
<div class="m-12 grid grid-cols-7 grid-rows-4 border-2 border-red-500 bg-slate-100">
  <div class="borderGray row-start-4"><p class="textClass">Some Text/Link</p></div>
  <div class="slantedLine row-start-4"></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-2 row-start-3"></div>
  <div class="borderGray col-start-3 row-start-3"><p class="textClass">Some Text/Link</p></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-4 row-start-3"></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-4 row-start-2"></div>
  <div class="borderGray col-start-5 row-start-2"><p class="textClass">Some Text/Link</p></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-6 row-start-2"></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-6"></div>
  <div class="borderGray"><p class="textClass">Some Text/Link</p></div>
</div>

<div class="m-12 grid grid-cols-11 grid-rows-4 border-2 border-red-500 bg-slate-100">
  <div class="borderGray col-span-2 row-start-4"><p class="textClass">Some Text/Link</p></div>
  <div class="slantedLine row-start-4"></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-3 row-start-3"></div>
  <div class="borderGray col-span-2 col-start-4 row-start-3"><p class="textClass">Some Text/Link</p></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-6 row-start-2"></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-6 row-start-3"></div>
  <div class="borderGray col-span-2 col-start-7 row-start-2"><p class="textClass">Some Text/Link</p></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-9"></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-9"></div>
  <div class="borderGray col-span-2 col-start-10 row-start-1"><p class="textClass">Some Text/Link</p></div>
</div>

<div class="grid-cols-15 m-12 grid grid-rows-4 border-2 border-red-500 bg-slate-100">
  <div class="borderGray col-span-3 row-start-4"><p class="textClass">Some Text/Link</p></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-4 row-start-4"></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-4 row-start-3"></div>
  <div class="borderGray col-span-3 col-start-5 row-start-3"><p class="textClass">Some Text/Link</p></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-8 row-start-2"></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-8 row-start-3"></div>
  <div class="borderGray col-span-3 col-start-9 row-start-2"><p class="textClass">Some Text/Link</p></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-12"></div>
  <div class="slantedLine col-start-12"></div>
  <div class="borderGray col-span-3 col-start-13 row-start-1"><p class="textClass">Some Text/Link</p></div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/mw1mGqKwlf?file=css)

---

#### Explanation:

There are three differences between the variations:

1. The `col-span-{n}` of each text's container. [Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-column)
2. The `grid-cols-{n}` and `grid-rows-{n}`. [Docs-1](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns) [Docs-2](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-rows)
3. The `col-start-{n}` and `row-start-{n}` of each element inside the `grid`. [Docs-1](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-row) [Docs-2](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-column)

Let's take the second variation to demonstrate. Let's take off the classes to understand how it works:
[image: no classes]

Each odd-numbered element is simply the area for the text. We insert a paragraph in those divs to show the desired text/link:
[image: added text classes]

Each even-numbered element is an area for the diagonal class (`slantedLine`). The diagonal line goes from the bottom-left corner to the upper-right corner. When we put two elements with this kind of line on each other, we get the effect of a diagonal border on the top and bottom:
[image: added slanted classes]

And together:
[image: end-result]

---

It might not give you the exact design you were looking for, but it can give you an idea of how to progress from here.

Let me know if you have questions.
I hope it helped.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the idea. We will definitely use this approach.