# Drawing diagonal lines in html5

Tags: html, css

Given a div of unknown dimensions how can I draw a solid line from one corner to the diagonally opposite corner without using JavaScript?

I thought the CSS3 `calc()` function might help me here but it seems you can't pull values from the height and width into another property (e.g. transform or background-image)
I was hoping I could do something like:

```
transform: rotate ( calc(atan(height / width)) rad);
```

(The calculation is probably wrong but more important is that the syntax is totally invented.)

I am targeting Firefox for this project but would prefer something that will work in any modern browser.

Comment: can you use javascript/jquery?

Comment: "without using JavaScript", so I guess not.

Comment: Sorry my mistake @Diodeus, skipped over that part.

Comment: Related?: [Is it possible to draw a diagonal line using CSS3?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4538368/456814).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an SVG:

```
<svg style='width: 200px; height: 200px;'>
    <line x1="0" y1="200" x2="200" y2="0"
        style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
</svg>
```

With percentage coordinates, if needs be:

```
<svg style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'>
    <line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0"
        style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qXKfN/2/

<sup>(Should work in [FF, Chrome, Safari, and IE >= 9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5))</sup>

---

At various sizes in various browsers, the SVG might be pushed out of its container. One solution is to set `line-height: 0px;`. Another solution, and probably the preferred solution, is to set `position: relative;` on the container and `position: absolute;` on the SVG.

http://jsfiddle.net/qXKfN/3/

Comment: Actually - It seems to break if the height is < 15px. The line is drawn outside the box.

Comment: @DJL Not sure what to tell ya. I'll experiment with it when I'm not mobile.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use plugin: 
https://bitbucket.org/stopsopa/jquery.line
I couldn't find tools to draw such lines on top of divs in way that don't block clicks beneath, then idea of creating this plugin was born.

Plugin is based on transform-rotate (css3) and one div element.

Using:

```
$.line(0, 0, 500, 1000);
```

or

```
$('selector').line(0, 0, 500, 1000);
```

you can also change color or width of line:

```
$('selector').line(0, 0, 500, 1000, {
   css : {
       borderTop: '5px solid red'
   }
});
```

and you have also callback function:

```
$('selector').line(0, 0, 500, 1000, {
   css : {
       borderTop: '5px solid red'
   }
}, function (linediv, opt) {
    linediv.css({
        borderBottom : '1px solid black'
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey don't ban this plugin, this is good work, well documented and i really did research to develop this plugin.

Comment: @user1338731 Sorry for the ban. I contacted a moderator and he lifted it. However, if you wrote the plugin yourself you should add something like «**Disclaimer:** I am the developer of the plugin.» to avoid misflagging as spam.

Comment: And also explain a bit what your plugin does: rotate-transform a border-top.

Comment: Ok, i'm new here so i will remember that for the future.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you don't want to use SVG as suggested. Here is an example of pure HTML + vanilla JS code to draw a line from any `X1,Y1` to any `X2,Y2` in any color & width.

```js
function drawLine(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, color, width) {
  let x1 = X1, y1 = Y1, x2 = X2, y2 = Y2;
  if (X1 > X2) { x1 = X2; y1 = Y2; x2 = X1; y2 = Y1 }
  const dx = x1 - x2
  const dy = y1 - y2
  const d = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
  const a = Math.atan(dy / dx)
  
  const element = document.createElement('span')
  element.style = `border-top:solid ${color} ${width}px;position:absolute;top: ${y1}px;left:${x1}px;width:${d}px;height:0;transform:translate(-${d/2}px,0) rotate(${a}rad) translate(${d/2}px,0)`
    document.getElementById('root').appendChild(element)
}

drawLine(10, 10, 100, 200, 'red', 5)
drawLine(15, 150, 300, 30, 'green', 15)
```

```html
<div id="root" style="position:relative">
</div>
```

Comment: This answer does not confoirm to the request of "without using JavaScript" as per the OP's original question.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my line. It's SVG and it's as simple as possible. Easily sizable by their parent element.

```html
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 100 100"
      preserveAspectRatio="none"
    >
      <line
        x1="0"
        y1="100"
        x2="100"
        y2="0"
        stroke="black"
      />
    </svg>
```

Comment: How is this different from the 10yrs-ago accepted answer?

Comment: Readability counts, smartypants.